# get horizontal and vertical accuracy in android device

Tags: android, geolocation

I am developing location tracker application in android.
When

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    System.out.println(location);
    }
    so it gives meLocation[mProvider=network,mTime=1302690466456,mLatitude=21.1596426,mLongitude=72.8072426
,mHasAltitude=false,mAltitude=0.0,mHasSpeed=false,mSpeed=0.0,mHasBearing=false,mBearing=0.0
,mHasAccuracy=true,mAccuracy=75.0,mExtras=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=148]]
```

I want to get horizontal as well as vertical accuracy..
How to get these 2 values..
Thanks in advance

Comment: location management website in Android?

Answer (score 1):

It's been 8 years 3 months. Probably you have found the solution. It may help others like me who is looking for a help in getting horizonal and vertical accuracy.

In Android Location documentation, it states that

- getAccuracy()
  Get the estimated horizontal accuracy of this location, radial, in meters.
- getVerticalAccuracyMeters()
  Get the estimated vertical accuracy of this location, in meters.
- You may find all the location related services and functionalities in the following link managed by Android

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location

=======

Answer (score 1):

I do wanted achieve the same objective, well now you can achieve that and many other information which will be available in the location object which you may receive in `LocationCallback`. I have enabled a `Service` for fetching location, so `LocationCallback` is placed in my Serivce Class `LocationService`

For this, you have to call the `LocationCallback` object as stated below :

```
private lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback

locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            if (locationResult.lastLocation != null) {
                val location = locationResult.lastLocation
                val intent = Intent(ACTION_LOCATION_UPDATE)
                // Add the current location as an extra to the intent
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION, location)
                val latitude = locationResult.lastLocation!!.latitude
                val longitude = locationResult.lastLocation!!.longitude
                Log.d("LAT_LOND","Current Position : $latitude | $longitude")
                sendBroadcast(intent)

            }
        }
    }
```

Now you have to call the callback using `FusedLocationProviderClient`

```
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

  // Initialize fusedLocationClient
  fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

 //Calling the locationCallback object

  fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationUtils.getLocationRequest(),
        locationCallback,
        null
    )
```

Here, as you can see I have passed the whole object of **location** in a `BroadcastReceiver` because I wanted to display the information into an activity. Attaching the Activity code as well for your reference.

```
private val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == LocationService.ACTION_LOCATION_UPDATE) {
            val location = intent.getParcelableExtra<Location>(LocationService.EXTRA_LOCATION)
            // Updating the UI with the new location data
            binding.tvLat.text = location?.latitude.toString().trim()
            binding.tvLong.text = location?.longitude.toString().trim()
            binding.tvAcc.text = "${location?.accuracy.toString().trim()} meters in horizontal"
            binding.tvAccVer.text =
                "${location?.verticalAccuracyMeters.toString().trim()} meters in vertical"
            binding.tvTime.text = convertLongToTime(location?.time!!)
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that the object of `locationCallback` holds all the data, from this you can retrieve the information you need.

Also, keep a note in mind that you should enable all the required permissions for fetching location and receiving data of the location.

For better understanding, I am sharing a link where you can enable runtime permissions from the user and interact with the Application, so that the application does not behave improper.

LINK - [Runtime Location Permissions Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142331/how-to-request-location-permission-at-runtime)

Feel free to comment your thoughts on this and do suggest any changes if needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are no vertical or horizontal accuracy. Accuracy is applied to position at all.

Comment: there is vetcial accuracy, but android does not forward this info from the GPS chip.

Comment: There IS such a thing as vertical vs. horizontal accuracy, when it comes to GPS positioning. Without going into the maths - think about the fact that for GPS device to show altitude it usually needs one more satellite then the minimum for horizontal positioning.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to get horizontal accuracy read it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationProvider.html

Returns a constant describing horizontal accuracy of this provider. If the provider returns finer grain or exact location, ACCURACY_FINE is returned, otherwise if the location is only approximate then ACCURACY_COARSE is returned.

Comment: This is for when we select provider if we choose only GPS and then want to find vertical and horizontal accuracy at that time this is not useful