# How to request Location Permission at runtime

Tags: java, android

In the manifest file I added permissions coarse and fine, and when I run on device with Android 6, nothing happens! I try 
everything but no way to get location updates...

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    String provider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location != null) {

            Log.i("Location Info", "Location achieved!");

        } else {

            Log.i("Location Info", "No location :(");

        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Double lat = location.getLatitude();
        Double lng = location.getLongitude();

        Log.i("Location info: Lat", lat.toString());
        Log.i("Location info: Lng", lng.toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void getLocation(View view) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        onLocationChanged(location);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You need to actually request the Location permission at runtime (notice the comments in your code stating this).

**Updated with Kotlin and background location for API 31 (Android 12):**

Starting with API 30 background location must be requested separately.
This example is using `targetSdk 31` and `compileSdk 31`.
Note that it's possible to bundle the background location request along with the main location request on API 29, however to do that you would need to maintain three separate code paths.
It's easier to just break it out to separate requests for 29 and above.

Be sure to include the latest location services in the app level gradle (18.0.0 at the time of writing):

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0"
```

Include the location permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

This is a simplified example that does handle most cases, but in a simplified way.  In the case where a user chooses "Don't ask again", on the next app launch it will open up the settings for the user to manually enable the permission.

Full activity code:

```kotlin
import android.Manifest
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Looper
import android.provider.Settings
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.google.android.gms.location.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var fusedLocationProvider: FusedLocationProviderClient? = null
    private val locationRequest: LocationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
        interval = 30
        fastestInterval = 10
        priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
        maxWaitTime = 60
    }

    private var locationCallback: LocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            val locationList = locationResult.locations
            if (locationList.isNotEmpty()) {
                //The last location in the list is the newest
                val location = locationList.last()
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "Got Location: " + location.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                )
                    .show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        fusedLocationProvider = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        checkLocationPermission()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {

            fusedLocationProvider?.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationRequest,
                locationCallback,
                Looper.getMainLooper()
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            )
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {

            fusedLocationProvider?.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
        }
    }

    private fun checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                )
            ) {
                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                    .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                    .setPositiveButton(
                        "OK"
                    ) { _, _ ->
                        //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                        requestLocationPermission()
                    }
                    .create()
                    .show()
            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                requestLocationPermission()
            }
        } else {
            checkBackgroundLocation()
        }
    }

    private fun checkBackgroundLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            requestBackgroundLocationPermission()
        }
    }

    private fun requestLocationPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            ),
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION
        )
    }

    private fun requestBackgroundLocationPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                ),
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
            )
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        when (requestCode) {
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION -> {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // location-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
                        fusedLocationProvider?.requestLocationUpdates(
                            locationRequest,
                            locationCallback,
                            Looper.getMainLooper()
                        )

                        // Now check background location
                        checkBackgroundLocation()
                    }

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    // Check if we are in a state where the user has denied the permission and
                    // selected Don't ask again
                    if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                            this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                        )
                    ) {
                        startActivity(
                            Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                                Uri.fromParts("package", this.packageName, null),
                            ),
                        )
                    }
                }
                return
            }
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION -> {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // location-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
                        fusedLocationProvider?.requestLocationUpdates(
                            locationRequest,
                            locationCallback,
                            Looper.getMainLooper()
                        )

                        Toast.makeText(
                            this,
                            "Granted Background Location Permission",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    }
                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                return

            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99
        private const val MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION = 66
    }
}
```

On Android 10 (API 29) it will give the user the choice to grant background location after the initial location request:

[image]

[image]

On Android 12 (API 31) it will do the same, but the interface is different:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Original Answer in Java:**

Here is tested and working code to request the Location permission.

Put this code in the Activity:

```java
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.title_location_permission)
                    .setMessage(R.string.text_location_permission)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // location-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    //Request location updates:
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
                }

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.

            }
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Then call the `checkLocationPermission()` method in `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //.........

    checkLocationPermission();
}
```

You can then use `onResume()` and `onPause()` exactly as it is in the question.

Here is a condensed version that is a bit more clean:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is 'provider'? and is 'MainActivity' the activity from which permission is requested?

Comment: @AbdullahUmer You can see how `provider` is used in the question: `String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);`

Comment: And yes, MainActivity is the Activity where this code would go in this example. Take a look at MainActivity in the question for more context.

Comment: nice example. Thanks!. Watch out for the gotcha.. Make sure you're using `android.Manifest`.  Android Studio seems to default to `my.app.package.Manifest` instead.

Comment: Warning: If a user denies location permissions and clicks `Don't show again`, your app will lag or crash because there will be constant calls to request permission. A quick fix is to move the call to `checkLocationPermission()` from `onResume()` to `onMapReady()`.

Comment: @hexicle You're right.  I just ran this code as it was, and it definitely wasn't working properly.  The easiest fix is just to call `checkLocationPermission()` in `onCreate()` instead, so I modified the answer to do that.  With this solution, you can use `onResume()` and `onPause()` exactly as it is in the question.  Thank you for calling this to my attention, cheers!

Comment: The callback is not getting called

Comment: This solution seems incorrect for API 29. The `onRequestPermissionsResult` method is only checking the first item within `grantResults`. If the user doesn't accept the "all the time" permission location won't be recorded in the background. Also, with API 30 the request dialog will fail to show (you can't request background location at the same time).

Comment: @masterwok Yeah this was just a quick example, I need to come back and update it a bit when I have time.  I was not aware of the API 30 issue, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @DanielNugent, I've posted my solution/example below for reference. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: I have tried to run your suggested java example and I am getting the following errors: ```java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=99, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.location_check/com.example.location_check.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid null provider
```

This happens when I grant permission. I have debug prints in onPause and onResume methods and it seems that this error happens during onPause execution

Comment: @TheBestPlayer Make sure you are initializing the provider, you have to use that code from the `onCreate()` method in the question.
`provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);`

Comment: `onRequestPermissionsResult()` is deprecated

Answer (score 37):

Google has created a library for easy Permissions management. Its called [EasyPermissions](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions)

Here is a simple example on requesting Location permission using this library.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        requestLocationPermission();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        // Forward results to EasyPermissions
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
    }

    @AfterPermissionGranted(REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION)
    public void requestLocationPermission() {
        String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
        if(EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, perms)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "Please grant the location permission", REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION, perms);
        }
    }
}
```

`@AfterPermissionsGranted(REQUEST_CODE)` is used to indicate the method that needs to be executed after a permission request with the request code `REQUEST_CODE` has been granted.

This above case, the method `requestLocationPermission()` method is called if the user grants the permission to access location services. So, that method acts as both a callback and a method to request the permissions.

You can implement separate callbacks for permission granted and permission denied as well. It is explained in the github page.

Comment: Thats a very helpful to mention this library, thank you very much

Answer (score 17):

Location permission privacy change in **Android 10** or **Android Q**.

We have to define additional **`ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`** permission if user wants to access their current location in background so user needs to granted permission **runtime** also in `requestPermission()`

If we are using lower than Android 10 device then *`ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`* permission **allow automatically** with `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission

This tabular format might be easy to understand what if we don't specify `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` in manifest file.

[image]

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" /> // here we defined ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION for Android 10 device
```

MainActivity.java
Call `checkRunTimePermission()` in `onCreate()` or `onResume()`

```
public void checkRunTimePermission() {
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || 
             ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED||
             ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(context);

        } else {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        10);
        }
   } else {
            gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(context); //GPSTracker is class that is used for retrieve user current location
   }
}

 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 10) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(context);
        } else {
            if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                // If User Checked 'Don't Show Again' checkbox for runtime permission, then navigate user to Settings
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                dialog.setTitle("Permission Required");
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setMessage("You have to Allow permission to access user location");
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.fromParts("package",
                                context.getPackageName(), null));
                        //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivityForResult(i, 1001);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = dialog.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
            //code for deny
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1001:
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED 
                        || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(context);
                    if (gpsTracker.canGetLocation()) {
                        latitude = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
                        longitude = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
                    }
                } else {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION},10);
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

build.gradle (app level)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29 //should be >= 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.runtimepermission"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29 //should be >= 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/d40cht/gps-android/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/gpstracking/GPSTracker.java) you can find `GPSTracker.java` file code

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your answer. Do you have any idea how can I determine whether the user selected "always allow" option or "one-time-use" option??

Comment: @MohammadZarei Glad to help you, if answer is helpful then please upvote my answer and Yes, you can track record,there is  `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method and in that there is one argument `int[] grantResults` in that you have to write for loop _for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
                Log.d("TAG", "onRequestPermissionsResult: " + grantResult);
            }_ if grantResult **0** then permission granted else **-1** then pemission denied.

Comment: In both "always allow" and "one-time-use" the permission granted, but if the user chooses "one-time-use", next time he comes back our app, must give us the same permission. I want to know if we can check if he permitted us permanently or not?

Comment: @MohammadZarei So you have to store flag in `sharedPreference` in `onRequestPermissionsResult()`. when user choose on "one-time-use" permission then you have to set flag to `true` (by default it set to false) and in `MainActivity` you have get value from preference and check whether it true or false

Comment: Yes, but I couldn’t find a way to say either the user chose "one-time" or always. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: But somehow playconsole is rejecting app even i mention about background location in app , playconsole and even in privacy policy any idea?

Answer (score 6):

Below is my solution to requesting foreground and background location permissions on 28 and below, 29, and 30. The differences between the APIs are subtle but important.

**API 28 and below**, the system treats foreground and background location permissions as the same. If you grant location permissions, then the application is granted both implicitly.

**API 29**, you can request both foreground and background permissions at the same time.

**API 30**, you must request foreground location permissions and then only request background location permissions after the foreground location permissions have been granted. If you ask for both foreground and background permissions at the same time, then the system will ignore the request. Another difference is that the user must allow background location permissions within the application location permission settings rather than through a system dialog.

The solution below only starts the specified action (e.g. background location tracking) only after the user has accepted both foreground and background location tracking:

**LocationPermissionUtil.kt**

```
private const val REQUEST_CODE_FOREGROUND = 1
private const val REQUEST_CODE_FOREGROUND_AND_BACKGROUND = 2

object LocationPermissionUtil {

    private fun Context.isPermissionGranted(permission: String): Boolean = ActivityCompat
        .checkSelfPermission(this, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    private val Context.isFineLocationPermissionGranted
        get() = isPermissionGranted(
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        )

    private val Context.isBackgroundPermissionGranted
        get() = when {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q -> ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            else -> isFineLocationPermissionGranted
        }

    private val Context.isFineAndBackgroundLocationPermissionsGranted
        get() = isFineLocationPermissionGranted && isBackgroundPermissionGranted

    private fun Activity.checkFineLocationPermission() {
        if (isFineLocationPermissionGranted) return

        val shouldShowFineLocationPermissionRationale = ActivityCompat
            .shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            )

        if (shouldShowFineLocationPermissionRationale) {
            presentAlertDialog(
                R.string.dialog_fine_location_rationale_title,
                R.string.dialog_fine_location_rationale_description,
                R.string.yes,
            ) {
                requestLocationPermissions()
            }
        } else {
            requestLocationPermissions()
        }
    }

    private fun Activity.requestLocationPermissions() =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            requestFineLocationAndBackground()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                REQUEST_CODE_FOREGROUND
            )
        }

    @TargetApi(29)
    private fun Activity.requestFineLocationAndBackground() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
            ),
            REQUEST_CODE_FOREGROUND_AND_BACKGROUND
        )
    }

    @TargetApi(29)
    private fun Activity.checkBackgroundLocationPermission() {
        if (isFineAndBackgroundLocationPermissionsGranted) return

        val shouldShowBackgroundPermissionRationale = ActivityCompat
            .shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
            )

        if (shouldShowBackgroundPermissionRationale) {
            presentAlertDialog(
                R.string.dialog_background_location_rationale_title,
                R.string.dialog_background_location_rationale_description,
                R.string.yes,
            ) {
                requestFineLocationAndBackground()
            }
        } else {
            requestFineLocationAndBackground()
        }
    }

    fun checkLocationPermissions(activity: Activity, action: () -> Unit) = with(activity) {
        if (isFineAndBackgroundLocationPermissionsGranted) {
            action()
            return
        }

        checkFineLocationPermission()
    }

    fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        activity: Activity,
        requestCode: Int,
        action: () -> Unit
    ) = with(activity) {
        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_CODE_FOREGROUND -> {
                if (!isFineLocationPermissionGranted) {
                    checkFineLocationPermission()
                    return
                }

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                    checkBackgroundLocationPermission()
                } else {
                    action()
                }
            }
            REQUEST_CODE_FOREGROUND_AND_BACKGROUND -> {
                if (!isFineLocationPermissionGranted) {
                    checkFineLocationPermission()
                    return
                }

                if (isBackgroundPermissionGranted) {
                    action()
                } else {
                    checkBackgroundLocationPermission()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        LocationPermissionUtil.checkLocationPermissions(this, this::onLocationPermissionsGranted)
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        LocationPermissionUtil.onRequestPermissionsResult(
            this,
            requestCode,
            this::onLocationPermissionsGranted
        )
    }

    private fun onLocationPermissionsGranted() {
        Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Background location permitted, starting location tracking...",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello @masterwok What is presentAlertDialog? Android studio can't resolve this.

Comment: It's a custom dialog I wrote to present rationale to the user. Any dialog will do here. The purpose is to let the user know why you're requesting permission before you request it and to give them the opportunity to deny the request (that way you don't just ask using the system API because after a few attempts the system will prevent you from asking the user).

Answer (score 3):

check this code from MainActivity

```
 // Check location permission is granted - if it is, start
// the service, otherwise request the permission
fun checkOrAskLocationPermission(callback: () -> Unit) {
    // Check GPS is enabled
    val lm = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enable location services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        buildAlertMessageNoGps(this)
        return
    }

    // Check location permission is granted - if it is, start
    // the service, otherwise request the permission
    val permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        callback.invoke()
    } else {
        // callback will be inside the activity's onRequestPermissionsResult(
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST
        )
    }
}
```

plus

```
   override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
              // Permission ok. Do work.
         }
    }
}
```

plus

```
 fun buildAlertMessageNoGps(context: Context) {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage("Your GPS is disabled. Do you want to enable it?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ -> context.startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)) }
        .setNegativeButton("No") { dialog, _ -> dialog.cancel(); }
    val alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

usage

```
checkOrAskLocationPermission() {
            // Permission ok. Do work.
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code work for me. I also handled case "Never Ask Me"

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

In build.gradle (Module: app)

```
dependencies {
    ....
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"
}
```

This is CurrentLocationManager.kt

```
import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.IntentSender
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationListener
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.CountDownTimer
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import android.util.Log
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference


object CurrentLocationManager : LocationListener {

    const val REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_LOCATION = 123

    fun checkLocationPermission(activity: Activity) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                activity,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_LOCATION
            )
        } else {
            Thread(Runnable {
                // Moves the current Thread into the background
                android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND)
                //
                requestLocationUpdates(activity)
            }).start()
        }
    }

    /**
     * be used in HomeActivity.
     */
    const val REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 55
    /**
     * The number of millis in the future from the call to start().
     * until the countdown is done and onFinish() is called.
     *
     *
     * It is also the interval along the way to receive onTick(long) callbacks.
     */
    private const val TWENTY_SECS: Long = 20000
    /**
     * Timer to get location from history when requestLocationUpdates don't return result.
     */
    private var mCountDownTimer: CountDownTimer? = null
    /**
     * WeakReference of current activity.
     */
    private var mWeakReferenceActivity: WeakReference<Activity>? = null
    /**
     * user's location.
     */
    var currentLocation: Location? = null

    @Synchronized
    fun requestLocationUpdates(activity: Activity) {
        if (mWeakReferenceActivity == null) {
            mWeakReferenceActivity = WeakReference(activity)
        } else {
            mWeakReferenceActivity?.clear()
            mWeakReferenceActivity = WeakReference(activity)
        }
        //create location request: https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html#prompt
        val mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()
        // Which your app prefers to receive location updates. Note that the location updates may be
        // faster than this rate, or slower than this rate, or there may be no updates at all
        // (if the device has no connectivity)
        mLocationRequest.interval = 20000
        //This method sets the fastest rate in milliseconds at which your app can handle location updates.
        // You need to set this rate because other apps also affect the rate at which updates are sent
        mLocationRequest.fastestInterval = 10000
        mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

        //Get Current Location Settings
        val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest)
        //Next check whether the current location settings are satisfied
        val client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(activity)
        val task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
        //Prompt the User to Change Location Settings
        task.addOnSuccessListener(activity) {
            Log.d("CurrentLocationManager", "OnSuccessListener")
            // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location requests here.
            // If it's failed, the result after user updated setting is sent to onActivityResult of HomeActivity.
            val activity1 = mWeakReferenceActivity?.get()
            if (activity1 != null) {
                startRequestLocationUpdate(activity1.applicationContext)
            }
        }

        task.addOnFailureListener(activity) { e ->
            Log.d("CurrentLocationManager", "addOnFailureListener")
            val statusCode = (e as ApiException).statusCode
            when (statusCode) {
                CommonStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED ->
                    // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                    // by showing the user a dialog.
                    try {
                        val activity1 = mWeakReferenceActivity?.get()
                        if (activity1 != null) {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            val resolvable = e as ResolvableApiException
                            resolvable.startResolutionForResult(
                                activity1, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS
                            )
                        }
                    } catch (sendEx: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                        sendEx.printStackTrace()
                    }

                LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way
                    // to fix the settings so we won't show the dialog.
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun startRequestLocationUpdate(appContext: Context) {
        val mLocationManager = appContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                appContext.applicationContext,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            //Utilities.showProgressDialog(mWeakReferenceActivity.get());
            if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 0f, this
                )
            } else {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0f, this
                )
            }
        }

        /*Timer to call getLastKnownLocation() when requestLocationUpdates don 't return result*/
        countDownUpdateLocation()
    }

    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
        if (location != null) {
            stopRequestLocationUpdates()
            currentLocation = location
        }
    }

    override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String, status: Int, extras: Bundle) {

    }

    override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {

    }

    override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {

    }

    /**
     * Init CountDownTimer to to get location from history when requestLocationUpdates don't return result.
     */
    @Synchronized
    private fun countDownUpdateLocation() {
        mCountDownTimer?.cancel()
        mCountDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(TWENTY_SECS, TWENTY_SECS) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {}

            override fun onFinish() {
                if (mWeakReferenceActivity != null) {
                    val activity = mWeakReferenceActivity?.get()
                    if (activity != null && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            activity,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
                        val location = (activity.applicationContext
                            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager)
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER)
                        stopRequestLocationUpdates()
                        onLocationChanged(location)
                    } else {
                        stopRequestLocationUpdates()
                    }
                } else {
                    mCountDownTimer?.cancel()
                    mCountDownTimer = null
                }
            }
        }.start()
    }

    /**
     * The method must be called in onDestroy() of activity to
     * removeUpdateLocation and cancel CountDownTimer.
     */
    fun stopRequestLocationUpdates() {
        val activity = mWeakReferenceActivity?.get()
        if (activity != null) {
            /*if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {*/
            (activity.applicationContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager).removeUpdates(this)
            /*}*/
        }
        mCountDownTimer?.cancel()
        mCountDownTimer = null
    }
}
```

In MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
...
CurrentLocationManager.checkLocationPermission(this@LoginActivity)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
        CurrentLocationManager.stopRequestLocationUpdates()
        super.onDestroy()
    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == CurrentLocationManager.REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                //denied
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                builder.setMessage("We need permission to use your location for the purpose of finding friends near you.")
                    .setTitle("Device Location Required")
                    .setIcon(com.eswapp.R.drawable.ic_info)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ ->
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                                this,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                            )
                        ) {
                            //only deny
                            CurrentLocationManager.checkLocationPermission(this@LoginActivity)
                        } else {
                            //never ask again
                            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
                            val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
                            intent.data = uri
                            startActivityForResult(intent, CurrentLocationManager.REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS)
                        }
                    }
                    .setNegativeButton("Ask Me Later") { _, _ ->

                    }
                // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
                val dialog = builder.create()
                dialog.show()
            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                CurrentLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(this)
            }
        }
    }

    //Forward Login result to the CallBackManager in OnActivityResult()
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        when (requestCode) {
            //case 1. After you allow the app access device location, Another dialog will be displayed to request you to turn on device location
            //case 2. Or You chosen Never Ask Again, you open device Setting and enable location permission
            CurrentLocationManager.REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS -> when (resultCode) {
                RESULT_OK -> {
                    Log.d("REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS", "RESULT_OK")
                    //case 1. You choose OK
                    CurrentLocationManager.startRequestLocationUpdate(applicationContext)
                }
                RESULT_CANCELED -> {
                    Log.d("REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS", "RESULT_CANCELED")
                    //case 1. You choose NO THANKS
                    //CurrentLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(this)

                    //case 2. In device Setting screen: user can enable or not enable location permission,
                    // so when user back to this activity, we should re-call checkLocationPermission()
                    CurrentLocationManager.checkLocationPermission(this@LoginActivity)
                }
                else -> {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }
            else -> {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: dude the question has JAVA and android tags... But Kotlin people always have to let you know

Answer (score 0):

After having it defined in your manifest file, a friendlier alternative to the native solution would be using Aaper: https://github.com/LikeTheSalad/aaper like so:

```
@EnsurePermissions(permissions = [Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION])
private fun scanForLocation() {
    // Your code that needs the location permission granted.
}
```

Disclaimer, I'm the creator of Aaper.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a simpler code? Try this!

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LoginActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CALL);
    }
```

Also, don't forget to ask for permissions obviously