# Error in startlocation update in request permissions

Tags: android, request

> i have an error that i cant fix and when i press alt+enter nothing
>   happens, i already added permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION etc  in the
>   manifest, can someone please help me ? i tried everything but nothing
>   seems to work

```
private void startLocationUpdates(){
            String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, PERMISSIONS[0])
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, PERMISSIONS[1])
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
    //gives me error in this activity.compat.request
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) this, PERMISSIONS, 0 );

            } else {

                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);// and error in this line too
                Toast.makeText(this, "sinal pedido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to also include `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission in your manifest

Comment: What is the error you get ??

Comment: http://prntscr.com/h8csqr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.title_location_permission)
                    .setMessage(R.string.text_location_permission)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // location-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    //Request location updates:
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
                }

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.

            }
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Then you would just modify your `onResume()` override to call `checkLocationPermission()`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (checkLocationPermission()) {
       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
           Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
           == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

             //Request location updates:
             locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
       }
    }

}
```

Source: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40142454/5437621)