# What is the Action/Intent to turn ON Location (GPS)

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, android-location

I would like to know the `Intent` command for Turning ON `GPS` automatically. I'm developing an Android app, and would like to enable the `GPS` without navigating to the settings page (Something similar to UBER). I'm looking for the Action/Intent that would trigger the LOCATION_ENABLE settings.

EX: android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS_ENABLE (Something similar to This)

Comment: If you could do that, there's be no point in having the permission.  You can turn it on if its just not currently turned on, but you can't enable it programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can not enable user's location automatically** but you need to request to users if they want to grant location permission to your app.

You will display a dialog to user explaining why do you need permission and depending upon user's interest they can enable or disable it.

For how to request location permission, please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142331/how-to-request-location-permission-at-runtime-on-android-6) question

**Update:**

To open native GPS Settings you can use [`Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS) action like below:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick reply. I totally agree with your point asking for permission, but I want to know if there is an ACTION Intent Code Line that will bring up the permission? Something similar to what Google's location API does.

Comment: @AntonyJohn please check my updated answer. Hope this what you needed

Comment: @AntonyJohn my pleasure. Please don't forget to **upvote** my answer as well.