# Can't access to location in webview

Tags: java, android

I create a native webview for android based on the react project.
I want to access my device location but when I open the app it shows an error: this my permissions added in android:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

In my `app.js` file I created a `useEffect` function for accesing my location like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positions => {
      /*
      setLat(positions.coords.latitude);
      setLon(positions.coords.longitude);
      */
      localStorage.setItem("lat", positions.coords.latitude);
      localStorage.setItem("lon", positions.coords.longitude);

    }, err => alert(err));
  }, [])
```

When I am raning the app it shows `alert` message
and belov is my java code:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            AlertDialog .Builder alertDialog;
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            alertDialog.setMessage("permite accesul la locatie")
                    .setTitle("eroare locatie");
            AlertDialog mesajEroare = alertDialog.create();
            mesajEroare.show();


        } else {
            mySite = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.site);
            mySite.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath( MainActivity.this.getFilesDir().getPath() );
            mySite.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                    callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
                }
            });
            WebSettings setari = mySite.getSettings();
            setari.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            setari.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            setari.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            setari.setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + mySite.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");
            setari.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
            mySite.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3000/");


        }
```

I don't know where is the problem!
Thank you!

Comment: Just guessing, but I think the permission is not granted. I'd think you need to show the permission promt yourself in the `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt` function and then call the callback method with the result. You can check the permission state of an app in the system settings.

Comment: You need to request the permissions at runtime. Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142331/how-to-request-location-permission-at-runtime

Comment: @Jannik Can you shows the code ?

Comment: I cannot show you the code because I've never written it. But check out the question mentioned by Ignacio. The answer there is applicable for you as well. You only need to modify `onRequestPermissionsResult` a bit. Instead of calling `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates` you'd invoke the callback you recieved in `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt`.