# Google Nearby - Connections API - Discovery not working

Tags: android, wifip2p, google-nearby-connections

so recently my friends and i thought about creating an app that allows somewhat of realtime communication between the connected devices, without the need of a webserver. More explicitily, it should be an app, where a single device (master/host) create a game/session and multiple devices (slaves/clients) can join. after establishing all necessary connections (4-5 clients), the host should be able to broadcast data to the clients. Hence i researched a bit and if i understand it correctly the best guess for android are either the WiFi direct oder the google nearby connections api.

**Q1**. Is this the most simple approach to the desired goal ? or is this already too deep?

So i played a bit around with the connections api, i made a simple application and just used the code from the [Nearby Documentation](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview). Since im new to Kotlin, it could also be a rather simple mistake, however after a 2 hours, i swapped back to java with the same error. when the clients try to discover the host, they triggered their OnFailureListener. I tried to search for a solution online (including SO), but i could not find any useful information.

Im testing the application on a HTC ONE M8 and a Samsung Galaxy S7. To Ensure the Nearby Connection API features should work I also downloaded 2 [example apps](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-nearby) and those worked just fine. I tried how these handled the usage of the api but could not find the important part.

**Q2**. Where do i use the API wrong ? Or is it really just a error in the coding ?

**MainActivity.kt**

```
private const val TAG = android.R.attr.packageNames.toString() + "/Filter"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var connectionClient : ConnectionsClient

private val payloadCallback = object : PayloadCallback() {
    override fun onPayloadReceived(p0: String, p1: Payload) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Payload Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onPayloadTransferUpdate(p0: String, p1: PayloadTransferUpdate) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Payload Transfer Update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}

private val connPoint = object : ConnectionLifecycleCallback() {
    override fun onConnectionInitiated(p0: String, p1: ConnectionInfo) {
        connectionClient.acceptConnection(p0, payloadCallback)
        Log.i(TAG, "OnConnectionInitiated")
    }

    override fun onConnectionResult(p0: String, p1: ConnectionResolution) {
        when(p1.status.statusCode){
            ConnectionsStatusCodes.STATUS_OK -> Log.i(TAG, "ConnectionsStatusCodes STATUS_OK")
            ConnectionsStatusCodes.STATUS_CONNECTION_REJECTED -> Log.i(TAG, "ConnectionsStatusCodes STATUS_CONNECTION_REJECTED")
            ConnectionsStatusCodes.STATUS_ERROR -> Log.i(TAG, "ConnectionsStatusCodes STATUS_ERROR")
            else -> Log.i(TAG, "ConnectionsStatusCodes STATUS_UNKNOWN")
        }
    }

    override fun onDisconnected(p0: String) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onDisconnected $p0")
    }

}

private val endPoint = object : EndpointDiscoveryCallback() {
    override fun onEndpointFound(p0: String, p1: DiscoveredEndpointInfo) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onEndpointFound ID: $p0 Name: ${p1.endpointName} ")
        connectionClient.requestConnection(p1.endpointName, p0, connPoint)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.i(TAG, "OnSuccessListener requestConnection")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.i(TAG, "OnFailureListener requestConnection")
            }
    }

    override fun onEndpointLost(p0: String) {
        Log.i(TAG, "$p0 disconnected")
    }

}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    connectionClient = Nearby.getConnectionsClient(this.applicationContext)
    //Toast.makeText(applicationContext, connectionClient.instanceId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    setButtonOnClick()
}

override fun onStop() {
    connectionClient.stopAllEndpoints()
    connectionClient.stopAdvertising()
    connectionClient.stopDiscovery()
    super.onStop()
}

private fun setButtonOnClick(){
    val create = findViewById<Button>(R.id.create_btn)
    val join = findViewById<Button>(R.id.join_btn)
    create.setOnClickListener{ _ -> CreateGroup()}
    join.setOnClickListener{ _ -> JoinGroup()}
    Log.i(TAG, "On Click Listener set")
}

private fun CreateGroup(){
    Log.i(TAG, "Starting Advertising")
    connectionClient
        .startAdvertising(android.os.Build.MODEL,
            packageName.toString(),
            connPoint,
            AdvertisingOptions.Builder().apply{
                            setStrategy(Strategy.P2P_CLUSTER)
                            }.build())
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            OnSuccessListener<Void> {
                Log.i(TAG, "OnSuccessListener CreateGroup() was triggered")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            OnFailureListener {
                Log.i(TAG, "OnFailureListener CreateGroup() was triggered")
            }
        }
}

private fun JoinGroup(){
    Log.i(TAG, "Starting Discovering")
    connectionClient.startDiscovery(packageName.toString(),
        endPoint,
        DiscoveryOptions.Builder().apply{
        setStrategy(Strategy.P2P_CLUSTER)
        }.build())
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            OnSuccessListener<Void> {
                Log.i(TAG, "OnSuccessListener JoinGroup() was triggered")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            OnFailureListener {
                Log.i(TAG, "OnSuccessListener JoinGroup() was triggered")
            }
        }
}
```

}

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testapplication">

<!-- Required for Nearby Connections -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!-- Optional: only required for FILE payloads -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after figuring out how to correctly setup the Listeners using Kotlin i found out that i got the exception of a missing permission, 01-20 21:11:14.269 1058-1058/com.example.testapplication I/16843649/Filter: 8034: MISSING_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, which i thought was strange since its in the manifest. However i went to the normal app settings and turned on the permissions manually, and it works now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142331/how-to-request-location-permission-at-runtime You should request location permission at runtime.