# ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION Not Working on Lower Than Q (29) Android Versions

Tags: android, android-permissions

My app is targeting Android API 28.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/location#target-android-10), I should be requesting `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`, along with `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` when running on Android API < `29`.

I have tried doing this but in `onRequestPermissionResults()`, `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` is never granted and returns `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED`. I was under the impression this would be implicitly granted when requesting another foreground permission on < `29`.

Alternatively, I can remove the permission from the request on API < `29` and everything seems to work as expected but I am conscious that I would be going against the documentation.

**Question**

Can I omit an explicit request for the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` on Android versions < 29 and still work as expected whilst conforming to documentation in API `29` which works?

Comment: The `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` was added in API 29, so it doesn't exist in API 28 and lower.  It's not super clear, but the docs are probably talking about what happens when running on Android 10 or 11.  What version of Android are you testing on when it gets automatically denied?

Comment: I am compiling with API `29` but targetting API `28`. When testing I have tested on `23` mainly as well as `29` of course.

Comment: Interesting.  I would expect it to be denied on 23, but not on 29.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. You expectations are correct. It is denied on 23 but works as expected on 29. I don't know if you've checked the documentation I linked above but it clearly says to explicitly include the permission in the request

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense then.  On API 28 and lower, it's basically a no-op, since the permission doesn't exist in the code on those versions of Android.

Comment: @DanielNugent could you please write up an answer and I'll accept it. I believe you are correct, just the documentation is not clear and misleading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation states:

> If your app targets Android 10 (API level 29) or lower, complete the
> following steps to request ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION:
>
> 1. Include the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission, as well as either
>    the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, in your
>    app's manifest.
> 2. Request the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission, as well as one of
>    the other location permissions: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or
>    ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. You can request these permissions in a single
>    operation.

This is a little ambiguous because they don't mention specifics about how to implement, but the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION was added in API 29, so it doesn't exist in API 28 and lower.

Apparently this wasn't the case in the past, but now if you try to use it for lower API levels, you'll get a warning:

[image]

You can just omit the request to `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` on API 28 or lower:

```
private fun requestLocationPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                ),
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION
        )
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION
        )
    }
}
```

Complete code available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40142454/4409409

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I agree with your answer. You do need API level checks because on lower than 29, when you request `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission, it's coming back as denied. You either need to ignore it on older versions or not even request it.

Comment: Got it.  I didn't realize that you did need the API version checks.  Updated the answer, let me know if it's correct now!