# ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION is not granted on Android 9 or older

Tags: android

I have listed this permission in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

However it is not granted on Pie or older, this returns false:

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

I thought that this was automatically granted on older devices?

Same behavior when targeting both api 29 and api 30.

Comment: I think this Link can help you:
[ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION Not Working on Lower Than Q (29)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60384554/access-background-location-not-working-on-lower-than-q-29-android-versions)

Answer (score 1):

This permission was added in api level 29. [source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)

So simply omit this permission. You still need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and/or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION [Access location in the background](https://developer.android.com/training/location/background#checklist)