# Location not granted on Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions

Even though I allow location access within the virtual phone it is stuck on "You need to grant permission to access location".

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when (requestCode) {
            1000 -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission granted
                } else {
                    // permission denied
                    Toast.makeText(this, "You need to grant permission to access location",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Location Permission for Api level 31 is a bit different.
[Location permission for API level 31](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40142454/13533028)

You can use a library called [EasyPermissions](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions) to make your life easier.

```
@AfterPermissionGranted(REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION)
    public void requestLocationPermission() {
        String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
        if(EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, perms)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "Please grant the location permission", REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION, perms);
        }
    }
```

[Easy Permission implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51350622/13533028)