# How to enable Location access programmatically in Android app?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an application and on a specific button click I need to check whether location access is enabled or not in client-side development if location services are not enabled show the dialog prompt. I also  want to check if the location within given radius get new activity else button enabled(false)

How to enable "Location access" Programmatically in android?

Comment: Start here: https://developer.android.com/training/location

Comment: Check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142331/how-to-request-location-permission-at-runtime