# Android WebView GeoLocation Issue

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I am trying to make an app which will give me the precise location of a person.

Now all of the html and PHP work was done to make it work on a browser, which it is.

[The Website Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2CK1.png)

Now when I try to do the same using WebView in Android Studio, the app doesn't ask me to use location, thus coming out as empty

[The App response in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dgIg.png)

Please Guide me

Here is the code that I am using

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context activityContext;
    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(final String origin, final GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt()");

                final boolean remember = false;
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle("Locations");
                builder.setMessage("Would like to use your Current Location ")
                        .setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // origin, allow, remember
                                callback.invoke(origin, true, remember);
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("Don't Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // origin, allow, remember
                                callback.invoke(origin, false, remember);
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://rkjrrampur.in/bobby/4a-track.html");

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:minHeight="4dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BOBBYTRACK"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You just show the prompt with no code inside to enable location from the device if u not implemented look through https://stackoverflow.com/a/40142454/5304075